# OpenGeo Suite start up failure

Tags: boundless-suite

I started the openGeo Suite 3.0.1 in Windows 8 and after a while I get this error:

`Giving up on starting the Suite as it is taking longer than expected`

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

That error happens when the server isn't started in five minutes. To get around this, you can try starting it using the **command line.** To do this, open the windows command line prompt,  navigate to the root of your installation,

`C:\Program Files\OpenGeo\OpenGeo Suite\`

and start the service

```
opengeo-suite start
```

Alternatively, you can also click the Start OpenGeo Suite button on your start menu

[image]

Hopefully, it would work this time. Good luck!

source: [Getsatisfaction](https://getsatisfaction.com/opengeo/topics/how_do_i_start_the_opengeo_suite_when_the_dashboard_says_its_taking_too_long)

Comment: I did this and after waiting a while, nothing happened.